# How to pass model from view to controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In view I received model of type `HistorySearch`. Then I want to resend this model to controller using `ajax`:

```
$("#exportCsv").click(function () {
    // get model as json
    var searchData = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model))';
    searchData = JSON.stringify({ 'search': searchData });

    $.ajax({
        //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: '@Url.Action("ExportToCsv", "BankCosts")',
        type: 'POST',  
        data: searchData,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
        },
        async: true,
    });
});
```

As you can see I had to comment `contentType` because for some reason with this passed model is set to `null` in controller.

Also, my controller is coded like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void ExportToCsv(HistorySearch search)
{
    // search properties are not filled. They are set to default value
}
```

The thing is binding is not working correctly. Received `search` properties are set to default values. Whats wrong there?

Comment: In Chrome or Firefox Developer Tools (F12), can you see from the **Network** tab that the parameters are sent to backend correctly?

Comment: You need to wrap your views content in a form. Serialize it and then submit it. Remove the dataType notation from your ajax call. This is the data type you are expecting back.. which is void.. not json. Leave the content type as well. This is now defaulting to application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8  which is what you need.

Comment: Remove the quotes around `@Html.Raw()` - but what in the world is the point of sending back exactly the same model you just sent to the view

Comment: @vahded yes. data is send correctly.

Comment: @wheels73 I want to asynchronous send data, so I decided to use jquery.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke thanks for reply, but still its not biding correctly. I want to export model data to `csv` file.

Comment: All you need is `data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model)),` (but if you do stringify the data, then you also need to set the `contentType: 'application/json'` option. But again, what is the point of this?

Comment: @StephenMuecke This view is showing user's filtered results. User can use some filtering options to display data. Now I want to be able to save that data to `csv` file. View is only displaying for example 10 of 50 result (because of pagination) so I have to send model which contains search criteria. Now, in controller I will use theese search criteria to get all results from database and save them to file.

Comment: You are sending back exactly the same model you sent to the view, not edited values!

Comment: @StephenMuecke User use some search criteria and click `submit` button. Then page is reloaded with new results. Page contains 10 of 50 results, but I want to save all results to file. I have to send search criteria model back to controller. Then I will get theese 50 results and save them to file. Using chrome debugger I can see that I am sending edited data, but for some reason binding is not working correctly and this is what I want to repair

Comment: Again, you are sending back exactly what the controller just sent to the view - its utterly pointless! If you want to send back the values of the form, then its `data: $('form').serialize(),`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I cant sent back values from form, because form constains only 10 elements from 50. My pagination is limiting displayed results to 10 per page. After deleting `stringify` line, `contentType` line and `dataType` line it seems to work properly. What should I do to send second object which is string array? Should I send that as a json or what?

Comment: What 2nd object? We have no idea what your model is of what your form is

Comment: @StephenMuecke a string array. I would like to send model and string array. Two different objects.

Comment: That is easy enough - but we cannot help if we have no idea what your model is or the data you want to send is

Answer (score 0):

The `JSON.stringify({ 'search': searchData })` will transform your object to string, so then will pass to your **ActionResult** a string instead of an object.
Remove the `JSON.stringify` and on ajax call change:

`$.ajax({url: '...', ..., data: { searchData }, ...`